Formula to find the header and sum hours
I have a auto-generated report from our time entry system. The report gives the name of the employee in one column, and hours worked in a separate column. However, I need to find a formula that will allow me to locate the lines that belong to the header and total per employee. I need this to be automated so I create a dashboard from the data drop report.
Employee hours report

I have tried creating a macro but It will only work if I can determine how many rows will be reported before hand.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. Use text tables instead. The ? help button on the editor toolbar explains how. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

You need SCAN() function. Can you show your desired output.

You added that you created a macro. The macro can determine how many rows you have using various methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba

This method is somewhat manual, but it gets the job done pretty quickly.
First select the range you want to fill in the blanks for, starting with the first cell with text you want filled down all the way to the last cell you want filled down to.
In my example, it'll be A3:A15.

In the Home menu, open the Find & Select dropdown and choose Go To Special... and select Blanks.

With the new selected range, type =A3 (or the first cell with text you want to filldown) and instead of just Enter press Ctrl+Enter (Cmd+Enter for Macs).

That will then fill each blank with the cell above it.

